# how to copy LPCSTR string to pointer to char array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, winapi, char

I am trying to copy LPCSTR value to pointer to char array. With this code I am getting runtime error and unable to diagnose the root cause here

My code shown below

```
    LPCSTR src = "R2C7YQT8"; 
    char *dest [4];
    memset(dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    strncpy_s(dest[0], sizeof(dest[0]), src, 12);
```

how to copy LPCSTR string to pointer to char array in C?

Comment: Solutions in C++ will be very different, since C++ is not the same language. I removed that tag since this is clearly "C"

Comment: `char *dest [4];` is an array of 4 pointers. Those pointers have to point to some valid, big enough memory for `strncpy_s` to work

Comment: As the first argument to `strncpy_s`, you must specify the memory address to which the characters should be copied. You must ensure that at this memory location, sufficient space has been allocated to store all the data. However, you are instead simply passing the memory address `NULL` (i.e. `0`). In order to allocate sufficient memory, you can either use `malloc` or declare an array of type `char` and provide its address.

Comment: Don't even consider Win API programming before you have studied arrays, pointers and basic string handling.

Comment: `LPCSTR` is an [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) type. It's rather unusual to want to use ABI types in client code. ABI types are useful when implementing (or interfacing with) a library that provides a binary contract. In your code you would probably just want to use `char const*` instead. Not that this solves your immediate issue, but it takes one complexity out of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strncpy_s(dest[0], sizeof(dest[0]), src, 12);` is telling `strncpy_s` to copy into whatever `dest[0]` points to. `dest[0]` is a `NULL` pointer (`dest` itself is an array of four such pointers), so you invoke undefined behavior by trying to write to where the `NULL` pointer points.

Either:

1. You need to make `dest` a `char` array of any appropriate size and copy to `dest` itself, or
2. You need to initialize the pointer in `dest[0]` to something useful (and sufficiently large) then copy into it.

In both cases, passing `sizeof(dest[0])` is wrong; you're telling it to copy a number of bytes equal to the size of one pointer, not the data it points to.

Case #1's solution:

```
LPCSTR src = "R2C7YQT8"; 
char dest[9]; // Allocate enough space for the whole string as plain char array; can use higher number if desired
memset(dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
strncpy_s(dest, sizeof(dest), src, 12); // copy to dest directly, sizeof(dest) okay because it's local array
```

Case #2's solution:

```
LPCSTR src = "R2C7YQT8"; 
char *dest[4];
memset(dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
size_t srclen = strlen(src); // Compute length of input string
dest[0] = malloc(srclen + 1);  // Allocate space + 1 byte for NUL terminator
strncpy_s(dest[0], srclen + 1, src, 12);  // Copy it up to that many characters
```

Note that case #1 can be simplified when it's a literal string to just:

```
char dest[] = "R2C7YQT8";
```

which will automatically size `dest` and initialize it directly with no intermediate steps (it might in fact perform a `memcpy`-like operation from global data for larger strings, or it might just insert direct stack manipulation that renders the bytes correct), but that's restricted to the literal string and direct initialization case (you couldn't do this with a `LPCSTR` passed to a function or the like).